# Keyboard with TAB key ('\t')

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, keyboard

I make lists and I'd love to have a keyboard with a TAB key that actually puts `\t` character within a text field without switching to the following field. I tried most keyboards and I'm dissatisfied over the lack of that feature. Some have the TAB key, but these don't work as expected (pressing TAB switches to the next input field).

There is SwiftKey and is the only one that does this, but it has no option to [disable predictions](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000474549-How-do-I-remove-the-prediction-bar-from-SwiftKey-You-can-t-?page=3#comments), which I find annoying.

Comment: @alecxs Unfortunatelly, TAB key does nothing. It just switches to next text field or a button.

Comment: true. i always use tab for autocomplete in terminal emulator, didn't realize this behaviour